# Flutter vertical align dropdown button with autocomplete

Tags: flutter, dart, drop-down-menu, autocomplete, vertical-alignment

Can anybody help to align verticaly dropdown button with autocomplete field in flutter ? It look's like below :
[image: Not aligned fields]

I was trying many different things but depends on emulator device it's always too tall or too short, or text hint is not verticaly aligned (damn). Here is a code for that:

```
                      height: 100.sp,
                      color: Colors.redAccent,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 4, bottom: 4),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            RangeField(),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 10.sp,
                            ),
                            Container(
                              width: 250.sp,
                              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(
                                    const Radius.circular(5.0)),
                              ),
                              child: Autocomplete<Polska>(
                                displayStringForOption: _displayStringForOption,
                                optionsBuilder:
                                    (TextEditingValue textEditingValue) {
                                  if (textEditingValue.text == '') {
                                    return const Iterable<Polska>.empty();
                                  }
                                  return polska.where((Polska option) {
                                    return option
                                        .toString()
                                        .toLowerCase()
                                        .contains(textEditingValue.text);
                                  });
                                },
                                onSelected: (Polska selection) {
                                  city.text = selection.city;
                                },
                                fieldViewBuilder: (context, controller,
                                    focusNode, onEditingComplete) {
                                  return TextField(
                                    controller: controller,
                                    focusNode: focusNode,
                                    onEditingComplete: onEditingComplete,
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                    textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      border: InputBorder.none,
                                      hintText: 'Miasto',
                                      hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                          fontFamily: 'Quicksand',
                                          color: Colors.deepOrange,
                                          fontSize: 30.sp),
                                    ),
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 30.sp,
                                      fontFamily: 'Quicksand',
                                    ),
                                  );
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 10.sp,
                            ),
                            Container(
      width: 250.sp,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(const Radius.circular(5.0))),
      child: DropdownButton(
        hint: Text("Cena"),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        items: [
          DropdownMenuItem(
            child: Text(" 0zł"),
            value: "0",
          ),
          DropdownMenuItem(
            child: Text(" 50zł"),
            value: "50",
          ),
          DropdownMenuItem(
            child: Text(" 100zł"),
            value: "100",
          ),
        ],
        value: priceSelector,
        underline: SizedBox(),
        onChanged: dropDownCallback,
        iconEnabledColor: Colors.deepOrange,
        iconSize: 0.sp,
        icon: null,
        style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'QuickSand', color: Colors.deepOrange, fontSize: 30.sp),
      ),
    )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
```

I was playing around height value and vertical axis alignment but it seems there is something different wrong with this code.

Comment: Ok i fixed that by wraping autocomplete field with container, setting height and centering. I hope it will stay well.

Comment: warp ur optionsViewBuilder with Align > Material > Container
add width and hight to container